# Instrumenting OkHttpClient

Tags: okhttp, codahale-metrics

I'm writing a small wrapper library that'll allow me to monitor the internals of an OkHttpClient using Dropwizard Metrics: https://github.com/raskasa/metrics-okhttp.

I'm having some trouble properly instrumenting the `ConnectionPool` - specifically, periodically calling `getConnectionCount()` to monitor the number of open TCP connections.

When an instance of `OkHttpClient` is initially created, `getConnectionPool()` is null - which I'm expecting.  But also, subsequent attempts to access the pool still return null even during/after executing some network requests.

I'm assuming there is proper way to monitor the `ConnectionPool` because it is a part of the public API, but I'm just not seeing it clearly at the moment.

So:

- Is there way to access the `ConnectionPool` at the point where `OkHttpClient.getConnectionPool()` is not `null`?
- If this isn't the best approach, any advice for going about this a better way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
OkHttpClient client = ...
client.setConnectionPool(ConnectionPool.getDefault());
```

That'll give you the same connection pool you'll get anyway, but it'll give it to you sooner.

Comment: Thanks!  Exactly what I needed.  Is the `ConnectionPool` unit test friendly?  Specifically, how is the pool cleaned up as soon as possible where you'll deal with timing issues in the unit tests?

If you can't provide a complete answer, pointing to a proper starting point for my own research could help as well.

Comment: Yup, it's all testable.